# How can I configure ingress ports in app service with docker image hosting? There exists no option

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, docker-image

I was trying to host a custom docker keycloak image in an **azure contain app.** There exists the ingress option but I had to choose another solution as the keycloak service was stopped every 3 minutes after last activity and I do not know why.

Then I tried to host the docker keycloak image in an **app service** but there is no ingress option...

My docker image:

```
keycloak:
    image: MyDomain/test/custom-keycloak:11.10.1
    container_name: keycloak
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
```

How can I access the server on port 8443 when there exists no ingress ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Service listens on one port and it's port 80. You can set the **WEBSITES_PORT** application setting to a different port if needed. In your case, 8080, but mapping 2 ports is not allowed.

Comment: So If I decide for https I would write 443:8443 because the browser https connection uses 443 and it would be forwarded to 8443?

Comment: App Service does TLS termination. You should use 8443:8443 and set WEBSITES_PORT to 8443.

Comment: yes in the docker compose file there is written 8443:8443. Ok thanks!